# Switching between venvs in VSCode

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm working through a tutorial in running python in VSCode and am struggling to switch to run numpy. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

```
import numpy as np

msg = "Roll a dice"
print(msg)

print(np.random.randint(1,9))
```

The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

That's despite using terminal to pip install numpy.

This appears on bottom right so I think the venv is set right:

[image]

But panel in the bottom middle points to a folder elsewhere.

[image]

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `numpy` may not be installed in the current virtual environment.
You can use the command `pip show numpy` in the terminal to check the installation location of `numpy`.

[image]

**Solution**: Install `numpy` for ***.venv*** or switch the interpreter to the one with `numpy` installed.

Of course you also need to pay attention to using **Python** extensions to execute scripts. If you use *CodeRunner*, some settings will not work.

`Run Python File` not `Run Code`.

[image]